# Spring-batch not getting the table prefix from setTablePrefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to use a different datasource for spring batch and created the below configuration class and autowired my required datasource to this as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobRepository).

I am using spring boot(2.2.6) and spring batch version 4.2.1.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracleDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        factory.setTablePrefix("MYDB.BATCH_");
        factory.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

But when I start my application with this , it never applies the setTablePrefix and it always **fails with
table not found error.**

I need to use above as I have two different datasource and I need spring batch to use my oracleDataSource
bean.

If I disable non oracleDataSource bean and move the proprieties to application.properties, everything works fine.

Please guide on how this can be fixed. I saw a similar issue here where the user was complaining about same table not found issue after extending DefaultBatchConfigurer class
[Spring batch tables in a different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039596/spring-batch-tables-in-a-different-schema)

Comment: In your answer, you say `I found that the table prefix was getting reset while creating the jobExplorer [..] I think this should be mentioned in the spring-batch documentation`: No, the prefix is not reset or overridden. The `JobRepository` and `JobExplorer` are different components and have two different factory beans to create them, so you need to set the prefix on both factory beans as you showed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging the spring-batch source code I found that the table prefix was getting reset while creating the jobExplorer. The fix that works is as below.

I think this should be mentioned in the spring-batch documentation as jobExplorer is commonly used and can reset the table prefix back to BATCH_ if not properly overridden as below.

```
   
@Configuration
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracleDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
   
   @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED");
        factory.setTablePrefix("MYDB.BATCH_");
        factory.setMaxVarCharLength(1000);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Override
    protected JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(createJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.setTablePrefix("MYDB.BATCH_");
        jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
    }
```